# Getting a nil/optional error while trying to append an element at a dictionary's key

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.
```

I think the problem mainly lies in my `textField`. So I tried unwrapping it by using `if let` as follows:

```
if let text = textField.text {
     addressDict[rowTapped]! += [text]
}
```

However, I still got the same error. So I tried the following:

```
let text: String = textField.text!
addressDict[rowTapped]! += [text]
```

But this didn't work either; that is, I got the same error.

So, I tried printing `textField.text` onto the console and it never was nil. The rest of my code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

var addressDict = Dictionary<Int, Array<String>>()

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    var rowTapped = 0


    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
        print(rowTapped)
        print(textField.text!)
        print(addressDict)
        addressDict[rowTapped]! += [textField.text!] //getting the same error
    }
```

Anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Check whether addressDict[rowTapped]  is nil!. Problem seems to lie there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @Dev and and @NRitH answers, I came up with a solution that seems to work. The thing is, I never use `rowInfo`. It just acts like a checker to see if it is a nil. And the reason why I don't use it is because when I do rowInfo += [textField.text!], the textField.text doesn't go into this dictionary, that is, it doesn't get appended. But if I do:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let rowInfo = addressDict[rowTapped] {
            addressDict[rowTapped]! += [textField.text!]
        } else {
            addressDict[rowTapped] = [textField.text!]

        }
    }
```

It gets appended and works. However, I'm not sure why `rowInfo += [textField.text!]` doesn't work.

Edit: You can also write the following so that you don't have the awkward `rowInfo` there:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
        if addressDict[rowTapped] != nil {
            addressDict[rowTapped]! += [textField.text!]
        } else {
            addressDict[rowTapped] = [textField.text!]
        }
        print(addressDict)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using

```
addressDict[rowTapped]! += [textField.text!]
```

means

```
addressDict[rowTapped]! = addressDict[rowTapped]! + [textField.text!]
```

Initially there is no value in the dictionary for "rowTapped" key (Means array is nil) to append textField.text. That's why the fatal error is happening. So initialize that array and try appending.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first check whether `addressDict[rowTapped]` is nil.

```
if let rowInfo = addressDict[rowTapped] {
    rowInfo.append(textField.text!)
} else {
    // Create an entry for the row.
    addressDict[rowTapped] = [textField.text]
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message for the line `rowInfo.append(textField.text!)` and the line `addressDict[rowTapped] = [textField.text]`. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: For the first line, the error message is `operand of postfix "!" should have optional type; type is [String]` And for the second, it is `Cannot assign a value of type [String?] to a value of type Array<String>?`

Comment: Yes. You're trying to mix optionals and non-optionals. Optionals can be `nil`, so if you want to use them, you have to unwrap them by either doing an `if let x = optionalX` or using the postfix `!`. Your first error says that you're trying to unwrap something that's not optional, so delete the `!`.

Comment: The second error is because you're trying to assign a non-optional array of optional `String`s to an optional array of non-optional `String`s. Do you see the difference?

Comment: I would like to ask you another question. I rewrote the code so that it got rid of all the error messages but it's still not doing what I would like it do. Could we talk in a private message? Please?

Comment: Would you like to explain how you got it working? Future readers with the same question as you may find it useful.